# How to retrieve request from ionic2 App in php file

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am new to ionic2 and a bit confused about the best approach to retrieve the request send from app to a php file..

I am integrating my app with laravel PHP framework ..
 Currently I am able to access request if using

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Here I am posting data to php server using ionic2:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/lara/blog/public/api/apis/login', JSON.stringify({email: email,password: password}), { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {

});

public function apiLogin(Request $request)
```

- Actually the issue is that when using postman I am able to get request in $request but when sending from ionic2 I am not getting it in $request but getting in $postdata..
- So whats the correct way to retrieve in PPH or if I am sending it in a wrong way ..

  Can any one please suggest?

Comment: "i am not getting it in $request but getting in $postdata." what does it mean? are u using another variable $request in php?

Comment: Yes actually in laravell on using postman i can easily get request in $request as :public function apiLogin(Request $request)
{ print_r($request);  } .......  but when sending request using ionic i am not getting it in $request .. insteed i have to use $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");   ..... so is this fine or its not a good thing i am a bit confused

Comment: what are the headers u used in postman and ionic 2?

Comment: In ionic : header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');   and in postman: content type : json

Comment: that is server side header,not in ionic

Comment: ohk actually i think the issue is that i am not setting content type json in ionic2 .... actually i tryied to do that but it rendered some error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting in $postData because you are basically sending json data.
[Check here about reading json post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

you are setting body as:

```
JSON.stringify({email: email,password: password})
```

so header becomes: `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

You can set

```
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

and body as:

```
"email="+email+"&password="+password
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Suraj worked like a charm again. Thanks a lot.